# Can't click element in a treeview - Selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, treeview

I'm trying to reach an element by clicking through a treeview. I'm able to click through the 1st level 'Devices' but I'm stuck to go to the next levels.

Here is a screenshot from the browser window.

[image: Tree view of the webapp]

Here is the cut down version of the HTML code.

```html
<ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children" role="group">
  <li role="treeitem" id="devices" class="jstree-node jstree-open">
    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
    <a class="jstree-anchor" id="devices_anchor">
      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i> Devices
    </a>
    <ul role="group" class="jstree-children" style="">
      <li role="treeitem" id="j1_3" class="jstree-node jstree-open">
        <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
        <a class="jstree-anchor" id="j1_3_anchor">
          <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i> HANDSET
        </a>
        <ul role="group" class="jstree-children" style="">
          <li role="treeitem" id="j1_6" class="jstree-node jstree-open">
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
            <a class="jstree-anchor  jstree-clicked" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="j1_6_anchor">
              <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i> Apple
            </a>
            <ul role="group" class="jstree-children" style="">
              <li role="treeitem" id="j1_15" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf">
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
                <a class="jstree-anchor" id="j1_15_anchor">
                  <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i> iPhone 5s
                </a>
              </li>
              <li role="treeitem" id="j1_16" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf">
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
                <a class="jstree-anchor" id="j1_16_anchor">
                  <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i> iPhone 6
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Here is how I was able to click the first tree icon element in the treeview for 'Devices'

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#devices > i.jstree-icon.jstree-ocl")).click();
```

After that I don't know how to click the subsequent tree icons next to HANDSET --> Apple --> iPhone 6 to reach iPhone 6 page.

I simply **can't use IDs** because they can change as soon as another item is added to the treeview.

I tried something like this but that didn't work for me.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'HANDSET')]/../preceding-sibling::i[@class='i.jstree-icon.jstree-ocl']")).click();
```

---

**UPDATE**: For those who land up here, this is how I was able to resolve it using @santhosh kumar's answer:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'HANDSET')]/parent::li/i")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Apple')]/parent::li/i")).click();
```

Comment: can you try this xpath. "//a[contains(text(),'iPhone 6')]"

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that'll not work because I can't click the text, I need to click the icon next to the text to be able to go one level down. BTW, for me to reach iPhone 6 I need to click through HANDSET -> Apple - iPhone 6.

Comment: For clicking on the headset dropdown(a kind of) use this, "//a[contains(text(),'HANDSET')]/parent::a"..., just replace the HANDSET with appropriate visible items.

Comment: I get the error _no such element: Unable to locate element_ when I run "//a[contains(text(),'HANDSET')]/parent::a" :-(

Comment: Can you check this? "//a[contains(text(),'HANDSET')]/parent::li/a"

Comment: You are a champ, @santhosh kumar ! I made a slight change to your code. I did this instead and it worked //a[contains(text(),'HANDSET')]/parent::li/i. Thank you very much for your assistance, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with this xpath please,

```
"//a[contains(text(),'HANDSET')]/parent::li/i"
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code without id:

```
List<WebElement> icons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//i[@class='jstree-icon jstree-ocl'"));
for (WebElement e : icons) {
 e.click(); // click each
}
```

in "for" you can `webElement.getAttribute` or `getCssValue` for build following element locators

hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for your answer @V.Rob. I unfortunately can't use those ids j1_3, j1_6, j1_15, etc. The reason is that they can change as soon a new element is added to the treeview. Please see last few lines of my question. Is there a way to get to the icons using the test HANDSET, Apple and iPhone 6?

Comment: Thanks for sending updated code. I'm get the following error for the first line of your updated code. 'org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException': invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //i[@class='jstree-icon jstree-ocl' because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@class='jstree-icon jstree-ocl' is not a valid XPath expression.' Is there any other way?

Comment: driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@*]/i[@class='jstree-icon jstree-ocl']"))